# How do I upgrade Kate editor to the latest version in Kubuntu 20.04?

Tags: apt, kubuntu, kate

I am running Kubuntu 20.04 with Kate editor pre-installed through Discover software center. Recently I've noticed, that the version of Kate I have is not the latest version available.

Latest available version of Kate editor in Discover software center is version **19.12.3**

The latest available version on kate-editor.org is kate-**22.12.2**

Tried running

```
apt update && apt upgrade
```

This did not upgrade my Kate to the newest version, and I think I know, why:

```
apt info kate
```

Returns "Version: 4:**19.12.3**-0ubuntu1" (the same outdated version I already have installed)

I suspect that this may be connected to the fact I am using an LTS version of Kubuntu, but I am not sure about that.

My question is: can I upgrade Kate editor to the latest available version using `apt` or `apt-get`? This feels like a trivial task, but I can't wrap my head around it

Comment: It you look at the versions of all the software installed with 20.04, you will probably find that few applications are at the latest version. This is by design. Either accept it or run some other bleeding edge system.

Comment: If using other Qt / KDE packages, I would not do that. Latest available for my gentoo is 22.12.2 which depends on qt* >= 5.15.5 and kde-frameworks >= 5.101.0 which are unlikely to be installed on your system.

Comment: Yeah, you right. Newest Kate version requires higher qt version that Kubuntu 20.04 has.

Comment: Maybe you can try flatpak? Otherwise the only option would be to build Kate yourself from source. You will need to download Qt from the Qt website, and then use that Qt to build Kate and necessary libraries that Kate needs. I used to do this on CentOS7 so it should be possible on the system that you use. See https://community.kde.org/Get_Involved/development. Besides that Kate has telegram/matrix groups so reach out to the devs and they maybe able to help you out :)

Comment: Yep, tried to do exactly that, but got the error during building new version of Kate. And I am not sure if upgrading Qt would be a great idea. I should probably switch to distro that already has appropriate version of Qt, since I am pretty new to Linux

Comment: @Linux_noob_2077 You do not and should not upgrade your system Qt or Kate. That will mess up the system. Instead download Qt separately https://download.qt.io/official_releases/online_installers/ and use that. kdesrc-build will take care of the rest. Of course you will have to tell kdesrc-build about the downloaded version of Qt

Comment: @Waqar Thank you for the tip, I'll try to do that just to test if I can build new version. Hopefully I won't mess up my system in the process : D

Answer (score 1):

Newest Kate version requires higher qt version than Kubuntu 20.04 has.
To be specific, 22.X versions of Kate requires Kubuntu 22.10.X